# How to prevent resizing when focusing on input text on mobile phone javascript site?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm setting up a webpage aimed to be used also with mobile phones.
It is similar to a terminal console written in js with the last line as input line of the console.
The problem here is that when I focus on the input line on android 4.4.4 with chrome the keyboard show up and the whole page is resized to fit the remaining part of the screen.

I would like the page to scroll down and the input text to be shown ABOVE the keyboard, or at least just to scroll down without resizing. 
Would be great, at least to avoid the annoing Flickering I am experincing while resizing happens.
Do you have any ideas on where to act? Javascript? Css? Or is this android related?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it currently does

Comment: Add a sample link (try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) to illustrate the problem you’re having.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to modify this: http://eblong.com/zarf/glulx/quixe/